# There is a file in ~/.cache/deja-dup/.. with 899G size

Tags: backup, deja-dup, cache, mail-server

I am running my mail server on ubuntu which has 1.2 TB in total space.

Today I realized there was an issue on my mail server, it was refusing sending/receiving mails due to storage which triggers port issues too.

First I removed my latest backup *which I shouldn't have done..*, then started to investigate real problem;

```
********@***:~/.cache/deja-dup/8f323f............/duplicity-full-signatures.20140724T223328Z.sigtar.part

-rw------ 1 ******* ******** 899G Aug 5 10:02 duplicity-full-signatures.20140724T223328Z.sigtar.part
```

What is that file used for?

Is it safe to remove it because the size is really really really huge.. 899G..

[image: [IMG URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94zd3.png)]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [bug/feature](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/385495). They seem to work on a fix.

Comment: Will it be safe to remove then? And what would happen if I re-backup files